# Is "Here is a thought" used as an opinion request question?

Tags: phrase-meaning, attachment-ambiguity

I think it's used:

1. just to introduce an idea/thought —here is a thought, life is worthy;
2. To request an opinion of an idea/thought —here is a thought, what if we go to the cinema?. It's not a complex question.  The literal meaning is for "introducing a thought/idea" I think.

My question is if it's okay to use it as an opinion request question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand your question. You want to know if you can use "Here is a thought" as an "opinion request question?" What is an "opinion request question?"

Comment: It's a compound noun: opinion-request = a request for an opinion; opinion-request  question= a question about an opinion request. I think I get your point, maybe it is redundant to use the words "request" and "question" in the same noun, but I hope you can understand me, I tried to form the question the best I could. making the question another way could be. can I use "here is a thought" to request an opinion about an idea?

Comment: Ah, I see, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a thought*. signals you are about to give an opinion.

"Here's a thought. Let's go to the movies".

It cannot be a question. The question would be:

Any thoughts? OR Do you have any thoughts? [on a subject].

**Let's go to the movies. Any thoughts?** [on that subject\

Comment: I would also say that, though in careful speech *here is a thought* only introduces an opinion or statement, in colloquial or rapid speech it's not uncommon to follow it with a question. In the US, I've heard people say "here's a thought, why don't you [insert vulgar phrase]" many times

Comment: thank you! you know I saw the translation taking a similar meaning to the pattern question "What do you think about...? so I was looking for someone else´s interpretation, so then I will use it that way of an "opinion mark" not a question jaja.

Comment: @GeorgeK. Following something with a question does not  mean the thing is a question and my example DOES just that.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure what you mean. If what follows it is a question, then what follows it is a question. My point is that in quick and careless everyday speech, sentences like "Here's a thought: should we go to the movies?" *do occur*. They are careless, and I would alter them if I was an editor, but they do not sound like *mistakes* to my ear. A quick google search for "here's a thought, should we" (in quotes) gives several pages of hits, some in published articles.

Comment: 'here's a thought' can be (at least in the UK) a way of politely prefacing a suggestion or idea to make it clear that the speaker is being tentative. It can also be sarcastic - Person A: Hey! My computer won't work! Person B: Here's a thought: is it switched on?

Comment: @GeorgeK. Sorry, I thought I had given an example like that: "Here's a thought. Shall we go to the movies?" But the careless speech part I disagree with. Your speech could be quite formal or informal. It doesn't matter.